# OTRS ITSMChange API service

Tags: python, otrs

Did anybody use to write services, connected with ITSMChangeManagement of OTRS? Is there any API to this thing? I need something like `GenericTicketConnector`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is nothing with ITSMChangeManagement. Only Tickets, FAQ and ConfigItems can be used with the GenericInterface of the Community Edition

Comment: Thanks  for the answer. As it can be concluded, there is no way to manage Changes of OTRS  from another app ?

Comment: This requires custom development.